# Minecraft server shortcut

Tags: minecraft

I would like to make a shortcut for a minecraft server.

I want it to launch  `cd Minecraft && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui`

I would also like to keep the terminal open so i can see the logs.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You mean a keyboard shortcut? If you want it in a terminal, then maybe an alias would do?

Comment: Do you just want a shorter command to run in the terminal? Or do you want to make an entry in the Launcher?

Comment: @insert_name_here I would like a desktop icon i can double click that will launch terminal and execute those commands, although a shorter command would also work

Answer (score 1):

You can make an alias for the command using the `alias` command:

```
alias 'start-minecraft-server'='cd Minecraft && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui'
```

Now the command `start-minecraft-server` will execute those commands. You should probably use an absolute path though, since otherwise it'll only work if you're in the right directory:

```
alias 'start-minecraft-server'='cd /path/to/Minecraft && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui'
```

Aliases are lost when you close your terminal, though. To make it permanent, you can add that `alias` command to `~/.bash_aliases`, which is read automatically when you start the terminal on Ubuntu.

---

You can also put a shortcut on the desktop. To do this, you will have to put a [`.desktop` file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) in `~/Desktop` (for example, `~/Desktop/minecraft_server.desktop`). Here is an example that should do what you want:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=bash -c 'cd /path/to/Minecraft && java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui'
Name=Minecraft Server
Comment=Start Minecraft server
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;
```

(replace `/path/to/Minecraft/` with the full path to the Minecraft directory)

Comment: When I execute the shortcut nothing happens.The GUI asked how I want to open it, I choose execute in terminal. It flashes open then closes, there server doesn't run in the background either

Comment: @Jack Odd. Try adding `; read` before the second `'` in the `Exec` line to keep the terminal open so you can see if there are any error messages.